# How to setup ESM for firebase functions?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, es6-modules

Our server app should use the latest [ipfs-http-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-http-client) since it is an official package to access IPFS but the project needs to use ESM for it from [v57.0.0](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/releases/tag/ipfs-http-client-v57.0.0). I have spent quite amount of time and been frustrating... I need some help.

I have referred:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=1st
- https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs/blob/master/docs/upgrading/v0.62-v0.63.md#esm
- https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html
- and many docs and stackoverflow

but I got an error when running firebase in local:

> ⬢  functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: admin.initializeApp is not a function

This is a blocker to run test, deploy as well, eventually we cannot forward.

I have created a clean and small project from scratch to make sure what the reason is as follows:

*package.json*

```json
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "exports": "./lib/index.js",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^11.8.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.3.1",
    "ipfs-http-client": "^60.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "private": true,
  "type": "module"
}
```

*tsconfig.json*

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,

    // ensures output is ESM
    // "module": "es2020", // NOT work
    // "module": "es2022", // NOT work
    "module": "esnext", // NOT work

    // "moduleResolution": "node16" // Compile error
    // "moduleResolution": "nodenext" // Compile error
    "moduleResolution": "node", // NOT work

    // support modern features like private identifiers
    // "target": "es2017", // NOT work
    // "target": "es2020", // NOT work
    "target": "es2022", // NOT work

    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

*functions/src/index.ts*

```js
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {create, IPFSHTTPClient} from "ipfs-http-client";
admin.initializeApp();

/**
 * create an ipfs client
 * @return {IPFSHTTPClient}
 */
function createIpfsClient(): IPFSHTTPClient {
  const endpoint = new URL("https://ipfs.infura.io:5001");
  const auth =
    `Basic ${Buffer.from("IPFS_USERNAME:IPFS_PASSWORD").toString("base64")}`;
  return create({
    host: endpoint.host,
    port: Number(endpoint.port),
    protocol: endpoint.protocol,
    headers: {
      authorization: auth,
    },
  });
}

export const createIpfs = functions.https.onRequest(async (_req, _res) => {
  const client = createIpfsClient();
  logger.info(client);
});
```

**Environment**

- os: macOS 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)
- node: v18.14.0
- firebase-tools: 12.0.0

**Steps to reproduce**

```
cd functions
yarn install
yarn serve
```

Comment: Copy all of the relevant code into the question itself. Don't link to GH.  If your repo ever goes away, that makes this question useless for others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import { initializeApp } from "firebase-admin/app"; // *** HERE
import {create, IPFSHTTPClient} from "ipfs-http-client";
initializeApp();  // *** HERE

/**
 * create an ipfs client
 * @return {IPFSHTTPClient}
 */
function createIpfsClient(): IPFSHTTPClient {
  const endpoint = new URL("https://ipfs.infura.io:5001");
  const auth =
    `Basic ${Buffer.from("IPFS_USERNAME:IPFS_PASSWORD").toString("base64")}`;
  return create({
    host: endpoint.host,
    port: Number(endpoint.port),
    protocol: endpoint.protocol,
    headers: {
      authorization: auth,
    },
  });
}

export const createIpfs = functions.https.onRequest(async (_req, _res) => {
  const client = createIpfsClient();
  logger.info(client);
});
```